# Proof of laws of logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm really confused with laws of logic unlike truth tables. Here, i'm trying to prove:

$$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\implies \lnot q \equiv p \lor\lnot q$$

LHS:

\begin{align}&&(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)⇒ \lnot q\\
\equiv&& \lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \lor \lnot q  \tag{by Implication law}\\
\equiv&&p \lor q \lor \lnot q       \tag{by Double Negation law}\end{align}

I'm stuck till there where I have no idea on how to get rid of $q$ as it seemed like I'm already close to the answer.

Comment: From 2nd to 3rd line you need De Morgan : $\lnot (\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \equiv (p \land q)$

Comment: You can do this using the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: You made a mistake in the last step: $¬(¬p∨¬q)∨¬q$ is equivalent to $(p{\color{red}∧}q)∨¬q$ – a negation of an alternative is a conjunction of negations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $$(\lnot p\lor\lnot q)\to(\lnot q\leftrightarrow(p\lor\lnot q))$$ is a tautology; that is, that the tableau of its negation is closed; but

[image]

is indeed closed. (Each path contains a contradiction.) Hence
$$(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\implies \lnot q \equiv p \lor\lnot q.$$

Comment: Please don't just insert a picture. Use MathJax instead...

Comment: @skyking I would usually but I'm using my phone at the moment; if you can put this picture into MathJax, though, please do.

Comment: @skyking See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/how-are-tableaux-presented-here/11543#11543) meta post of mine.

Comment: @Shaun thanks a lot. i wouldn't mind the picture as it would help me understand better. much thanks!

Comment: @Maxxx You're welcome. Please upvote my answer if you like it or even accept it if it answers your question & helps you learn.

Answer (score 1):

$\neg (\neg p \vee \neg q) \vee \neg q \equiv\\
(p\color{red}{\wedge} q) \vee \neg q \equiv\\
(p\vee\neg q)\wedge (q \vee \neg q) \equiv\\
(p\vee\neg q) \wedge \text{True} \equiv (p\vee\neg q) $

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array} {c|c}
\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\implies \lnot q&Premise\\
\hline
\lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)\lor \lnot q&Implication\\
\hline
(p\land q)\lor \lnot q&De Morgan\\
\hline
(p\lor \lnot q)\land(q\lor \lnot q)&Distribution\\
\hline
(p\lor \lnot q)\land1&Excluded\;Middle\\
\hline
p\lor \lnot q&Redundant\;Truth
\end{array}
$$

using [Propositional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms).